# ListView.Builder use under 2 StreamBuilders - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to
list the groupnames last updated order.

groupnames select in "user" collection, and last update check from "group" collection. I want to get result with merge them.

So, I used 1st StreamBuilder (snapshot) for user collection for get groupnames, nextly, I used 2nd StreamBuilder (snapshot2) to check which was last updated.

Please Help to complete my code,

There is screenshot of group collection
[image]

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(widget.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data['groups'] != null) {
              if (snapshot.data['groups'].length != 0) {
                // 2nd streamBuilder
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("groups")
                      .orderBy("LastUpdate")
                      .where("groupId",
                          isEqualTo: getId(snapshot.data["groups"][Index]))
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data['groups'].length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Center(
                          child: Text(snapshot.data["groups"][index]));
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return noGroupWidget();
              }
            } else {
              return noGroupWidget();
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            );
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(widget.uid)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data['groups'] != null) {
          if (snapshot.data['groups'].length != 0) {
            // 2nd streamBuilder
            return StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("groups")
                  .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
                  .where("groupId",
                      isEqualTo: getId(snapshot.data["groups"][Index]))
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data['groups'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Center(
                      child: Text(snapshot.data["groups"][index]));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return noGroupWidget();
          }
        } else {
          return noGroupWidget();
        }
      } else {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: It shows error -->` type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`


|||||||
Full error msg ---->

` ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#55f14]], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#63a47):`

Comment: .where("groupId",
                      isEqualTo: getId(snapshot.data["groups"][Index]), what is the value index in this line?

Comment: no value. my mistake. and run without it shows error --> field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Comment: plz check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815708/use-streambuilder-with-orderby-and-where