# Use StreamBuilder with orderBy and where

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection for Users and groups, I want to display list of last update groups. But, the user must be stay in member list of groupCollection.

There is a screenshot of group collection
[image]

So, I used  StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("groups")
            .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
            .where(
              "members",
              isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
            )
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data['members'] != null) {
              if (snapshot.data['members'].length != 0) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data['members'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(
                        snapshot.data["groupName"],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return noGroupWidget();
              }
            } else {
              return noGroupWidget();
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white),
            );
          }
        });
```

This showing always white color CircularProgressIndicator

Answer (score 2):

You're ignoring errors. When dealing with **any** `AsyncSnapshot`, always check for errors. For example with:

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
  }
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    ...
```

This will tell you the root cause of the problem.